# AVDs that exist do not get listed in the "Target Tab"

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, android-virtual-device

I am using emulator Android 2.1 with Eclipse. For few days I had the emulator working ... was able to debug... I had 2 AVDs created and was using one of them. Earlier today I had to move my classes to a different package. Ever since I did that the configuration that I had has disappeared . So now I had to create configuration - I select Android Application and then click New - gave it a name TestPrjCfg - when I go to the "Target" tab - I see "No AVD available" but when I click manager I see two AVDs listed. I tired refresh in the "Target" tab - the existing AVDs do not show up. I used the Manager and created a third AVD that did not help either. Please let me know what am I missing here? What should I do so that the existing AVDs showup in the "Target" tab?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it - The project was not compatible with the AVD.
The AVD supported Platform 2.1/API level 7, whereas the project had "Google APIs" selected - I thought "Google APIs" includes the platform too - anyway that is a different discussion I guess.

here is the message in the Console that help me identify the reason
...
[2010-06-01 16:42:44 - testprj]Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'.
[2010-06-01 16:43:16 - testprj]Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Google APIs': Aborting launch.
[2010-06-01 16:43:16 - testprj]Performing com.aie.testpk.TestStartsHere activity launch
....

Comment: Thanks for the update. Google APIs are for developing with Google-specific apps, such as Maps